# 'Tidy up' Oracle SQL report output

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

I am writing some SQL to output reports via SQL*Plus (Oracle Reflection). The output files (xlsx or lst) contain a lot of information that isn't needed in this instance, like below:

```
Session altered.

Enter value for 1: LIF
old   3: where a.group = '&&1'
new   3: where a.group = '123'

URN     |Title     |Forename                        |Middle Name | Surname        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     | Mx       | Smith                          |Bryn        | Paul

Rows Selected 1
```

I am looking to suppress the leading rows so that 'URN' is located in cells A1, the row of '-' separating the headers from the data and finally the 'rows selected' output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SET HEADING OFF
```

More info on the options [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm).

Edit: The option for removing the count of rows selected at the end is

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

just noticed it in the question.

Comment: Excellent thanks - usually get little from the Oracle notes but this is great. 

Recommend anyone looking at this question also look at THIS answer/resource

Comment: You could mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your question.

Comment: Accepted the answer as this report is now rolling - thanks again!

Comment: Cheers, glad it was of help